removing flashdrive app requirments
I bought a SanDisk iXpand flash drive (usb-c to lighting) hoping I could have it show up as a location in the file manager on my iPad to move files, not copy them. When I plugged it in told me to download an app and it was nothing I was hoping for. I decided to format it but it still shows the original manufacturer information on properties and continues to asks to be used with an app when I plug it in.
Does anyone know how to remove this so I can use it like a normal flash drive on my iPad? This was the only option I could find for a this type of double ended connection to use on all my devices.
